# Missing artifact for apache-drill

Tags: maven-3, apache-drill

I am following [documentation](http://drill.apache.org/docs/develop-a-simple-function/). As metioned there, I used the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
    <artifactId>drill-java-exec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

While building maven project, I got an error:

> Missing artifact org.apache.drill.exec:drill-java-exec:jar:1.0.0

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the maven central repository, I only see version 1.1.0 not 1.0.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
    <artifactId>drill-java-exec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe you need to change your version.

Answer (score 0):

Drill's artifacts are not in maven central, so install them from your local Drill installation:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/opt/apache-drill-1.0.0/jars/drill-java-exec-1.0.0-rebuffed.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.drill.exec -DartifactId=drill-java-exec -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/opt/apache-drill-1.0.0/jars/drill-common-1.0.0-rebuffed.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.drill -DartifactId=drill-common -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Comment: Drill's artifacts have been added to maven central since I wrote my answer.